# GraphQL: Are either of these two patterns better/worse?

Tags: graphql

I'm relatively new to GraphQL, and I've noticed that you can select related fields in one of two different ways.  Let's say we have a `droids` table and a `humans` table, and `droids` have an `owner` which is a record in the `humans` table.  There's (at least) two ways you can express this:

```
query DroidsQuery {
  id
  name
  owner {
    id
  }
}
```

or:

```
query DroidsQuery {
  id
  name
  ownerId # this resolves to owner.id
}
```

At first glance the former seems more idiomatic, and obviously if you're selecting multiple fields it has advantages (`owner { id name }` vs. having to make a new `ownerName` so you can do `ownerId ownerName`).  However, there's a certain explicitness to the `ownerId` style, as you're expressing "here's this thing I specifically expected you to select".

Also, from an implementation standpoint, it seems like `owner { id }` would lend itself to the resolver making an unnecessary `JOIN`, as it would translate `owner { id }` as the `id` column of the `humans` table (vs. an `ownerId` field which, with its own resolver, knows it doesn't need a JOIN to get the `owner_id` column of the `droids` table).

As I said, I'm new to GraphQL, so I'm sure there's plenty of nuances to this question that I'd appreciate if I'd been using it longer.  Therefore, I was hoping for insight from someone who has used GraphQL into the upsides/downsides of either approach.  And just to be clear (and to avoid having this answer closed) I'm looking for explicit "here's what is objectively bad/good about one approach over the other", not subjective "I prefer one approach" answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand GraphQL is just a query language + execution semantics. There are no restrictions on how you present your data and how you resolve your data.

Nothing stops you from doing what you describe, and returning both owner object and ownerId.

```
type Droid {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  owner: Human! # use it when you want to expand owner detail
  ownerId: ID! # use it when you just want to get id of owner
}
```

You already pointed out the main problem: **the former implementation seems more idiomatic**. No you don't make a idiomatic code, you make practical code.

A real world example as you design field pagination in GraphQL:

```
type Droid {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends(first: Int, after: String): [Human]
}
```

The first time, you query a droid + friends, and it is fine.

```
{
  query DroidsQuery {
    id
    name
    friends(first: 2) {
      name      
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you click more to load more friends; it hits `DroidsQuery` one more time to query the previous droid object before resolving the next friends:

```
{
  query DroidsQuery {
    id
    friends(first: 2, after: "dfasdf") {
      name      
    }
  }
}
```

So it is practical to have another `DroidFriendsQuery` query to directly resolve friends from droid id.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer, but I feel like what you're saying is "you can do it either way".  The thing is, I already know I can do it either way; what I'm really trying to understand is the advantages/disadvantages (ie. the trade-offs) of doing it one way or the other.